# Call execl on a non-const char[]

Tags: c++, execl

I'm getting the comand from keyboard in a `vector<string>` and I want to use in [`execl()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/execl), but execl() takes a `const char *`. Is there another function similar to `execl` I can use that takes `char*` parameters, or how can I call `execl` with my `char*`?

```
void Process::exec(string & program, vector<string> & params){
int i;
char x=program[0];
if(x=='/'){
    char * argq[params.size()];
        for(i=0;i<params.size();i++){
            argq[i]=(string_to_c_convert(params[i]));
        }

    if(params.size()==2){
        execl(argq[0],argq[0],(char *)0);
    }
    if(params.size()==3){
        execl(argq[0],argq[1],argq[2],(char *)0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Use execv which was created for exactly this reason?

Comment: I'm by no means an expert, and basically just looked up documentation (which may not even be official) but it _appears_ that [`execv` takes a `const char*`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/execv) as well.

Comment: @Tas it takes a pointer to an array of them. Am I understanding correctly that your problem is you want to be able to pass any number of parameters without copy-pasting code (to call `execl` with different numbers of parameters)?

Comment: but i need use absolute path

Comment: @Marcos.p well then `execv` sounds like exactly what you're looking for.  You can have an array whose size is the number of parameters (in fact you already have that) and you can pass that to `execv` the same way, no matter how many parameters there are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`const char *` doesn't mean that the argument *must* be `const`, it means it *can* be `const.`

There is no problem here to solve.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a [`std::string`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) out of your `char[]` and then use [`std::string::data()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/data/) which returns a `const char*`:

```
char * argq[params.size()];
    for(i=0;i<params.size();i++){
        argq[i]=(string_to_c_convert(params[i]));
    }

const std::string args(argq);
execl(args.data()[0], args.data()[1], 0);
```

Seeing as you already have a `std::vector<std::string>`, where I assume each `std::string` is actually just a single character (based on your loop and `string_to_c_convert` function), you could skip the `char[]` altogether and do the following:

```
execl(params[0].c_str(), params[1].c_str(), 0);
```